# jQuery: Loop to repeat a toggle show/hide for multiple classes named numerically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is kind of a weird question to put into words so apologies.

I am making a website with a timeline that has multiple data points. On click, each datapoint will open a unique popout window with content corresponding to the datapoint.

If I were to name each datapoint numerically, like ".datapoint-1" ".datapoint-2" and so-fourth, could I write a jQuery loop that would replace just making an individual click function for each datapoint and the corresponding popout window?

Right now I'm just showing and hiding divs (I know a lightbox would be an alternative method but I'm doing this for prototyping/learning experience)

Here's an example of the code for just the first popout window:

```
      $('.datapoint').click(function(){
    $(".popout").toggle();
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would use is a combination of class and a custom attribute like

```js
$('.datapoint').click(function() {
  var popout = $(this).data('popout');
  $(".popout-" + popout).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datapoint" data-popout="1">1</div>
<div class="popout popout-1">p-1</div>
<div class="datapoint" data-popout="2">2</div>
<div class="popout popout-2">p-2</div>
```

Here as you can see the class `datapoint` is used to have the click handler(or you can target the elements using the attribtue selector `'div[data-popuot]'`), then the attribute `data-popout` is used to target a specific `popout` element

Answer (score 0):

If your javascript is in a .php file, you can just write a for loop in php like this:

```
<script>
<?
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++) {
echo "$(\'.datapoint-".$x."\').click(function(){";
echo "$(\".popout\").toggle();";
echo "})\;";
} 
?>
</script>
```

I did not check my syntax but I hope this gives you an idea. There may be an alternative pure javascript way of doing it but I don't know what it is off the top of my head.